# The requested module '../node_modules/generate-serial-number/test/index.js' does not provide an export named 'generate'

Tags: javascript, browser, module, javascript-objects, node-modules

Hi I was trying to make an object with all details that a ticket have for that I used generate-serial-number module to generate a number for ticket earlier I was using

`const genrator = require(generate-serial-number);`

this was working fine in the console but when I tried to add that to an object in html the browser showed an error

> movies.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I searched online they recommend to use *import* instead of *require()*

but the error changed to

> The requested module '../node_modules/generate-serial-number/test/index.js' does not provide an export named 'generate'

Here's the code before adding import

```
var generator = require("generate-serial-number");

const seatNumberGenerator = () => {
  const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const randomLetter = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
  return `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}${randomLetter}`;
};

const showTimmings = (date, time) => {
  show = new Date(2023, 11, date, time, 0, 0, 0);
  return {
    showDate: `${show.getDate()}/${show.getMonth() + 1}`,
    showTime: `${show.getHours()}:00`,
  };
};

const Movies = [
  {
    name: "Animal",
    ticketPrice: 300,
    image: "../assets/images/animal-indian-movie-poster.jpg",
    rating: 3.9,
    genre: "Action/Crime",
    time: "3h 22m",
    seatNumber: seatNumberGenerator(),
    show: showTimmings(3, 1),
    ticketNumber: generator.generate(6),
  },
  {
    name: "Fukrey 3",
    ticketPrice: 300,
    rating: 2.9,
    genre: "Comedy/Thriller",
    time: "2h 27m",
    image: "../assets/images/fukrey-3-indian-movie-poster.jpg",
    seatNumber: seatNumberGenerator(),
    show: showTimmings(3, 16),
    ticketNumber: generator.generate(6),
  },
  {
    name: "Tiger 3",
    ticketPrice: 300,
    image: "../assets/images/tiger-3-indian-movie-poster.jpg",
    rating: 3.5,
    genre: "Action/Thriller",
    time: "2h 30m",
    seatNumber: seatNumberGenerator(),
    show: showTimmings(3, 20),
    ticketNumber: generator.generate(6),
  },
  {
    name: "Pathaan",
    ticketPrice: 300,
    image: "../assets/images/pathaan-indian-movie-poster.jpg",
    rating: 3.9,
    genre: "Action/Thriller",
    time: "2h 26m",
    seatNumber: seatNumberGenerator(),
    show: showTimmings(3, 23),
    ticketNumber: generator.generate(6),
  },
  {
    name: "Sam Bahadur",
    ticketPrice: 300,
    rating: 4.6,
    genre: "War/Drama",
    time: "2h 25m",
    image: "../assets/images/sam-bahadur-movie-poster.jpg",
    seatNumber: seatNumberGenerator(),
    show: showTimmings(3, 10),
    ticketNumber: generator.generate(6),
  },
];

export default Movies;
```

I tried changing it to import and even tried to check requirejs but that didn't work maybe i messsed up a little while implementing  requirejs

Comment: that's what you get for using a module abandoned 8 years ago :p what I don't get is why you're doing anything with `test/index.js` in that module

Comment: Maybe this answer can assit? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/3592771

Comment: `use import instead of require()` is your project set up to use ESModules rather than CommonJS? and why are you showing us `the code before adding import` when you say the error is when you DO use import?

Comment: Change your code to `import generator from 'generate-serial-number'`, then do `console.log(generator)` and show us the output